# Premiere CC Button Editor Unaligned

Tags: premiere, adobe, cc-2014

[image: Screenshot of button editing]
Above is the Screenshot of the results of adding new buttons using the the Premiere CC button editor. For the life of me I cannot get these buttons to align to center or align to anything at all. It's just arbitrarily looking like crap.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons will automatically allign to other button ontop or under existing buttons.
Right now they are not aligned because you are missing a spacer after the first two button in the bottom row. Or remove the spacer in the top row by dragging it into the editor window.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can't center them as well. No matter where I put a new button, they just arbitrarily push the other buttons in the row in one direction. How did you get them to be centered perfectly?

Comment: I just drag and drop them to the place I want them to be, just make sure you don't touch the button next to it.

Comment: Hm I tried this a while ago and it didn't seem to work, but I'll try it again later, thanks

Comment: Sadly they do not seem to align under each other no matter what I do. It seems like it is haphazard randomness at best and a bug more likely.

Comment: What you have to keep in mind you can't just place them anywhere, they will either snap to the left of an existing button or to the right depending on where you drag it to. When there is no button in the row yet it will place it always in the center.
But yes, they could definitely improve this "editor".